# Does Hardcore Mode increase drop and pet quality?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I know that Hardcore Mode increases the XP gain, but does it increase the quality of items and pets gained during the match?

Answer (score 7):

[Patch 7.20](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Patch_Notes_%28PC%29/Archives#7.20) on PC changed the reward behavior on PC:

> Hardcore Mode is now accessible on all Challenges, and gives better
>   reward items (on Campaign and Challenges) than non-Hardcore

This means pets gained in survival, or items gained as reward for beating a boss/challenge with hardcore mode enabled will yield better stats than a regular game.